# Spark Streaming + kafka INFO SimpleConsumer: Reconnect due to socket error: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

Tags: streaming, apache-kafka

Spark 1.6.2 (apache)
Kafka 2.1.1 (CDH 5.7.2)

```
val conf = new   SparkConf().setAppName("Test").setMaster("local[2]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(15))
val kafkaDStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topics)
```

I'm trying to use Spark Streaming to comsumer messages from Kafka . But when the program runs for some time ,i am getting the following info, then always output INFO SimpleConsumer: Reconnect due to socket error:                    java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException:

```
16/10/08 18:28:00 INFO SimpleConsumer: Reconnect due to socket error:                      java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
16/10/08 18:28:00 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922480000 ms
16/10/08 18:28:15 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922495000 ms
16/10/08 18:28:30 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922510000 ms
16/10/08 18:28:45 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922525000 ms
16/10/08 18:29:00 INFO SimpleConsumer: Reconnect due to socket error:     java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
16/10/08 18:29:00 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922540000 ms
16/10/08 18:29:15 INFO SimpleConsumer: Reconnect due to socket error:     java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
16/10/08 18:29:15 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922555000 ms
16/10/08 18:29:30 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922570000 ms
16/10/08 18:29:45 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922585000 ms
16/10/08 18:30:00 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922600000 ms
16/10/08 18:30:15 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922615000 ms
16/10/08 18:30:30 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922630000 ms
16/10/08 18:30:45 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922645000 ms
16/10/08 18:31:00 INFO SimpleConsumer: Reconnect due to socket error: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
16/10/08 18:31:00 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922660000 ms
16/10/08 18:31:15 INFO SimpleConsumer: Reconnect due to socket error: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
16/10/08 18:31:15 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922675000 ms
16/10/08 18:31:30 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922690000 ms
16/10/08 18:31:45 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922705000 ms
16/10/08 18:32:00 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922720000 ms
16/10/08 18:32:15 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922735000 ms
16/10/08 18:32:30 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922750000 ms
16/10/08 18:32:45 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922765000 ms
16/10/08 18:33:00 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922780000 ms
16/10/08 18:33:15 INFO SimpleConsumer: Reconnect due to socket error: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
16/10/08 18:33:15 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922795000 ms
16/10/08 18:33:30 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922810000 ms
16/10/08 18:33:45 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922825000 ms
16/10/08 18:34:00 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922840000 ms
16/10/08 18:34:15 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922855000 ms
16/10/08 18:34:30 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1475922870000 ms
16/10/08 18:34:45 INFO SimpleConsumer: Reconnect due to socket error: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: have you solved this issue ?

Comment: yeah, i have solved it, but it’s been too long, just remembered the piece of code -- kafkaDStream.foreachRDD had some promble.

Comment: Voting to close, as the asker already resolved it and cannot remember the solutin.